# IDialogService in design time

Tags: mvvm-light

I was fallowing Mix 2011 MVVM Deep dive talk and try to implement IDialogService interface to display messages and common loading bars... etc, but I found bit troubling assignment DialogService to ViewModel thru Views constructor. like this

```
((MasterViewModel) DataContext).DialogService = (IDialogService) App.Current;
```

This causing InvalidCastException in designg time, do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Tried using an 'as' instead of a cast?